# How to put two links in case when of jade?

Tags: pug, case-when

I use jade, and when I make two links in case when, it can not show right style.

I try to make multi lines, but it is wrong.

```
case pn >= page_count
    when true: |Next Last
    when false: a(href="/orders/list/#{pn+1}")Next a(href="/orders/list/#{page_count}")Last
```

Here pn is current page-number, page_count as literal meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation) syntax:

```
case pn >= page_count
    when true: | Next Last
    when false: | #[a(href="/orders/list/#{pn+1}") Next] #[a(href="/orders/list/#{page_count}") Last]
```